# Including Superagent as AMD

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, superagent

I am a little confused about multiple ways of importing files in Javascript (script tag, RequireJS, Component - if it is another way to include files). In my project, I am using AMD with RequireJS.
Now, I want to use [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) library.
I donwnloaded *superagent.js* file, and I included it in some test pages using *script* tag. Then, I can use a *require* function (defined in superagent.js), and I definitely have access to superagent functions, if I write:

```
var request = require('superagent');
```

in my JS file. 
Is there a way to use Superagent library in my poject, which is based on RequireJS? I hope to still use:

```
var request = require('superagent');
```

, but clearly it is not working.

Comment: Works for me (I did a quick check based on an [example template project](https://github.com/volojs/create-template)). Can you verify that the `superagent.js` resource is correctly loaded and doesn't 404? Superagent is AMD-ready so if the path is correct it will be picked up automatically. Can you be more specific than *"clearly it is not working"*?

Comment: I don't have 404, and I can see some code executed dureing _require_ function call, if I set some breakpoint in the code. But, if I use that line of code, _request_ is undefined.
Where did you get source code of superagent.js? I got it using `component install visionmedia/superagent` command and "compiling" it (I don't know more details about compilation, because I didn't make it on myself).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
require(["superagent"], function(superagent){
    console.log(superagent)
    // there your code 
})
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I am using the CommonJS syntax ([http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#exports]), and I'd like to use it. Anyway, I tried your suggestion, but superagent is yet undefined... I had a look at the code, and I am not sure that it can be used in AMD env, but I am not so expert.

Comment: Do you try to add this library to "shim" in Requirejs config ?http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: I didn't try, because this library defines again "require" function, which I use to include other AMD libraries with RequireJS. I found another solution, as explained in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a sort of workaround. 
I used "component" version of the library (even if I have no precise idea of what is component, so any help in this sense is appreciated), and I envelope it in a classical *define* RequireJS, without explicitly using *require*, as args passed to defining function (I don't need a require function, because it is defined in the library itself).

```
define(function () {
.... [all library content]...
return require("superagent");

});
```

I just added first line, and *return* before last line of library (which was simply *require("superagent")*). 
It seems to work, even if I remain confused about multiple ways to include JS files, and including JS libraries is nowaday every time an adventure...

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21023168/1906307) should clarify the differences between the multiple ways to call `require`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :
Create a require.config.js file call it say bootstrap.js, within that  choose a simple name for superagent. It'll look something like:

```
requirejs.config({
   map: {},
  paths: {
    'superagent': 'libs/superagent/superagent',
  },
  shim: {},
  packages: []
});

require(['js/main/main']);
```

In your index.html point require.js to bootsrap.js 
e.g.

Now in your modules use

```
define(
    ['superagent'],
    function(request) {
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry your index.html file should have within a script tag ' data-main="bootstrap" src="path-to-require.js" '