# Modules using RequireJS is not exported properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, node-modules, console.log

I am currently developing a local JavaScript app that will help me to dynamically generate some managerial documents such as invoices and vouchers for unpaid services for a specific client.

I'll be using node_modules, and so far I am using `(["jsonfile", "uniqid", "mkdirp"])` these modules need require to be stored in a variable.

The problem is that I am calling jsonfile as mention in its documentation

`var jsonfile = require("jsonfile");`

When `console.log(jsonfile)` from javascript file it returns `function localRequire()` unlike if i wrote that command inside browsers console .. for that it will return

```
>> console.log(jsonfile)
Object { spaces: null, readFile: readFile(), readFileSync: readFileSync(),     writeFile: writeFile(), writeFileSync: writeFileSync() } 
undefined
```

and to make the problem more complicated, when calling `readFile()` from console or from the script it returns that `readFile()` is not a defined function rather for jsonfile or `fs` which is a node module that is required for `jsonfile`

```
>>function readFile()
jsonfile.readFile()
TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
```

I don't really know what is the difference and how to use that variable from console than the variable of script. Especially that I don't redefine it in console after running the app.

Some code snippets you may need:

I am calling two scripts in `index.html`:

```
<!--requirejs -->
<script data-main="app" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<!-- a script which will use $ which is not defined -->
<script src="services/specifyDocType.js"></script>
<!--the script the call require and have the jsonfile variable -->
<script src="jsonfile-test.js"></script>
```

`app.js` code:

```
requirejs.config({
  //"baseUrl": "node_modules",
  "paths": {
    "app": "app",
    "jsonfile": "jsonfile/index",
    "graceful-fs": "jsonfile/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs",
    "fs": "/node_modules/jsonfile/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs",
    "jquery": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min"
    }
});

requirejs(["dist/js/main"]);
```

`main.js` :

```
define("jquery", function($) {
  $('body');
});
```

For the local script that will create jsonfile variable, here is the initial code I had to do the working test:

```
var data = 'DOCS/voucher/voucher.json';
var jsonfile = require(["node_modules/jsonfile/index"]);

console.log(jsonfile);
//this console that returns the function localRequire() mentioned above.

jsonfile.readFile(data, function(err, obj) {
    console.dir(obj);
});
```

For this app, I don't need to use a framework such as Angularjs, and I need to use require for each module I am using so far to create unique ids and directories in the root directory.

One more thing, this is my console on the first run:

```
function localRequire()  jsonfile-test.js:4:1
TypeError: jsonfile.readFile is not a function[Learn More]  jsonfile-test.js:6:1
ReferenceError: module is not defined[Learn More]  index.js:133:1
Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded  require.js:168:17
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

Comment: You explained too much but I am still confused what is your problem and what have you tried..

Comment: what a mess, you want to build something yet you are mixing backend code with client side code in a way that's impossible to work. I

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that RequireJS is a drop-in replacement for Node's `require` call. It isn't.

Node supports the CommonJS module system. RequireJS supports the Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) system. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21021621/1906307) for a question about the difference between the two.) It also provides support to *facilitate* consuming CommonJS modules, but it does *not* support consuming CommonJS modules *as-is*. At the very least, the CommonJS module must be wrapped in a `define` call. If you start with this CommonJS module, for instance:

```
function foo() {}

exports.foo = foo;
```

then you need at a minimum to convert it to this:

```
define(function (require, exports) {
  function foo() {}

  exports.foo = foo;
});
```

---

In addition, while RequireJS can consume CommonJS modules, it is not able to provide support for those modules that depend on the node VM. `fs` is one such module. It depends on the Node VM. It cannot be run in the browser. The DOM does not expose an API that the `fs` module could use to access the filesystem. `jsonfile` depends on `fs` so you cannot just load it with RequireJS in the browser. You *could* possibly find a module made to run in browsers that present an API compatible with `fs` and present a fake filesystem to the client code and this may work, but you have to do the job of finding the replacement module. RequireJS won't do this for you.

Comment: jsonfile is not a huge problem therefor i need to use uniqid and mkdirp ! and they use the same require of node

Comment: do you think i can solve this problem by running these codes as server side ?!

Comment: `mkdirp` also depends on Node-specific support. And yes, if you move the whole thing server-side, then you can just run the whole thing with Node and avoid using RequireJS and everything will work fine.