# webpack - When should I use require vs import for application.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpacker

I have hard time understanding the difference between "require" and "import" inside application.js file (Rails 6).

I've got an excerpt of Michael Hartl's book that describes the way to add jquery & bootstrap to my app.

Steps:

```
yarn add jquery@3.4.1 bootstrap@3.4.1
```

then add to config/webpack/environment.js

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

and finally in application.js:

```rb
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import "bootstrap"
```

The question is - why is jquery required, and bootstrap imported?
Thank you,

#### Update

EDIT - the comment by @arieljuod has helped me to look for solution in javascript realm, I'll leave the question just for future reference.
application.js is a javascript file and has nothing to do with rails itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export these are not rails concepts, you'll find way more information looking at javascript articles

Comment: Thank you, that's a valuable insight.

Comment: found this article to be insightful https://insights.untapt.com/webpack-import-require-and-you-3fd7f5ea93c0

Answer (score 1):

- In fact `require` is not a supported natively by browsers (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669665/using-javascript-require-and-import-on-browsers) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules))

  - This means that webpack will have to use `import` internally whenever you call `require`.
- compare [`import`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/ecma-script-modules/#importing) and [dynamic dependency management with `require`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/) from webpack doc.

**Thus:** I would use `require` for dynamic uses cases as shown in the doc examples and `import` everywhere else.

---

I am not sure if there are any side effects on treeshaking with using `require`. The [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) states that it depends on `import` and `export`

> Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax, i.e. `import` and `export`.

---

Just to not for the example with JQuery, the documentation recommends to use `ProvidePlugin` here instead:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery